# Including boost/asio.hpp throwing error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, boost-asio

When I use #include  in a header file, my program will no longer compile, giving the following error: `'boost::asio::basic_socket<Protocol,StreamSocketService>::cancel': By default, this function always fails with operation_not_supported when used on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, or earlier. Consult documentation for details.`

I am also using websocketpp in this project, if that is relevant - however the error only occurs if I include  specifically in my header.

I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 14.

I'm at a loss as to why this error is occuring. I do not have to use the library at all, simply include it.

Comment: Have you defined informed the compiler that you are targeting systems greater than Windows XP? In visual studio this should be in a property page somewhere, otherwise you likely need a something like `#define WIN32_WINNT 0x0600` where 0x0600 is the minimum version of Windows. you support.

Comment: Here we go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much, this was the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the header file, it's checking that `_WIN32_WINNT` is at least `0x0600`. Refering to [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx), you can decide which version to specify, e.g. `0x0600` for Windows Vista and above. Specify this line before the include statement:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
```

Comment: Adding `-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00` as a command line option for the compiler fixed the issue - thank you so much!